# R Programming-Creating New variable from values based on 100 Variables

Tags: r, analytics

I have set of 100 Variables from CFM_1 to CFM_100. Each variables can take any values from 1,2,3 or 4. I want to create a new variable called TEMP which will take value 1 if any of the CFM_1 to CFM_100 variable has value either 1 or 2. Please help me out with an appropriate R code for this

Comment: I edited my answer based on your comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your answers. Especially Shayaa. Amazing one.

Comment: You are welcome to click the check box near the answer to select one which helped you the most.

Comment: Done that. Can you please help me in one more thing. Let say i have variables called temp1 to temp20. I want to take the frequencies of all at one go. How can i do this?

Comment: clarify what you mean by frequencies and what you mean by one go. Do you mean the proportion of times that a particular row or column is 1,2,3,or 4 with respect to that row or column?

Comment: Hi Shayaa, So for eg in the dataset which you used, i want to look, how many times 1,2,3 and 4 appears in CFM_1 ,CFM_2 and so on for all the variables.

Comment: In One go mean, i want to write this using minimal syntax.

Comment: `df %>%lapply(table)`

Comment: Hey Shayaa....Your suggestion is working..But i am still not bale to decode the exact application of %>% operator.

Comment: It means insert the precedent data into the first argument of the antecedent call. It can be read "and then", e.g., take `df` and then lapply `table`.

Comment: HI Shayaa, One more thing. How can i use loops to do this task. Explaining again, I have dataset with 10 variables temp_1 to temp_5 and CFM_1 to CFM_5. All the variables has values ranging from 1,2,3 and 4. I want to make a new variable which will take value 1 if any of CFM_1 to CFM_5 takes value 1. how can i do this with the help of loops and not using apply functions. I have total of 10 rows in the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My example is a little silly, because the odds that a random variable will generate a 1 or a 2 in a single position in this matrix is 1/2. Do this ten times, one for each column of your matrix, and you have less than a 1% chance that your temp variable will be TRUE for any given row. Anyways, here goes.

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE)))
names(df) <- paste("CFM", 1:ncol(df), sep = "_")
```

Your data frame looks like this

```
 df
   CFM_1 CFM_2 CFM_3 CFM_4 CFM_5
1      2     2     1     4     4
2      2     2     1     3     4
3      2     1     1     3     3
4      1     2     3     3     2
5      3     4     2     4     4
6      3     4     4     2     2
7      3     1     3     2     2
8      1     2     4     1     2
9      3     2     1     3     2
10     1     3     1     4     3
```

Suppose now, that you have other variables in your data frame which you would like to exclude. We will prepend and append these columns to your data frame using cbind as follows.

```
df <- cbind(replicate(3,sample(1:4, 10, replace = T)),
      df,
      replicate(3,sample(1:4, 10, replace = T)))
names(df)[1:3]<- paste0("Var",1:3)
names(df)[9:11] <- paste0("Var", 9:11)
```

Now your df looks like this

```
df
    Var1 Var2 Var3 CFM_1 CFM_2 CFM_3 CFM_4 CFM_5 Var9 Var10 Var11
1     4    1    4     4     1     3     1     3    1     3     1
2     4    2    3     2     4     3     2     1    2     3     3
3     4    2    4     4     2     1     1     2    2     3     2
4     4    4    2     4     4     1     3     2    2     1     2
5     4    2    1     4     4     4     1     1    2     2     2
6     1    4    2     3     1     4     4     2    1     3     2
7     3    2    4     4     2     3     4     3    1     1     1
8     1    3    3     3     3     2     3     3    2     2     2
9     3    3    2     1     4     3     4     1    4     2     1
10    2    1    1     2     1     2     4     1    2     1     1
```

You can assign the values to the variable temp by applying the any function to the rows of the data to check if any of the data in each row is either a 1 or a 2. But first you need to find out which columns are your data.

You can use the `agrep` function to perform approximate string matching. It will tell you which names of your data frame had the characters `"CFM"` in them if you use

```
cfm_cols <-agrep("CFM", names(df))
cfm_cols
[1] 4 5 6 7 8

temp <- apply(df[,cfm_cols], 1, function(x) any(x) %in% c(1,2))
temp
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

as expected, they are all `TRUE`.

Another solution, if you would like, is to use the `dplyr` library for this

```
library(dplyr)
df%>% rowwise() %>% select(contains("CFM")) %>%
  mutate(TEMP = any(.) %in% c(1,2))
```

Comment: Just on the probability comment, the OP didn't say the variables were random. We don't know the distribution of values in this dataset. Values less than 3 may well be extremely rare.

Comment: @rosscova thanks! I meant, "my example", not "your example", since I sampled randomly. Anyways, I think I provided two efficient methods.

Comment: Ahh, I see, that makes sense :)... And yes, your answers are very efficient, especially with `dplyr`, nice work. I was trying something similar, but couldn't get it to work. Plus one for you.

Answer (score 1):

Edited with a more efficient solution, partly stolen/procured from @shayaa's answer...

The first line here creates a temporary dataframe by extracting only the columns you're interested in (we'll remove it when we're done with it):

```
new <- subset( df, select = paste0( "CFM_", seq_len( 100 ) ) )

df$TEMP <- 1 * ( apply( new, 1, min ) <= 2 )

rm( new )
```

So you're just searching each entire row for either of the values specified, and converting the boolean result to numeric, and placing that into your original dataframe.

Comment: Sorry i am unable to decipher this. If possible please explain this in a bit detail. Where does CFM variable comes into picture here?

Comment: Sorry, I should include the fact that I'm assuming the "100 variables" you mention are columns in a 100 column data frame. The code I provided looks at ALL columns, hence there's no need to call the columns by name. If there are more columns, which you'd need to exclude from the calculation, the code would change a little.

Comment: Yes the situation is i have the data frame with around 300 columns but i am only interested in the 100 out of those. I understood your explanation . But can you please let me know the change in syntax if i only want to include the ones i am interested in. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @PankajSinghi I've added a line to create the frame to work on. This will get you the result you're after, then put that result back into your original frame, and delete the temporary frame.

Comment: I figured out a more efficient solution within base R, thanks to @shayaa for the `apply` method. See edited answer